# Apache Airflow queue parameter not being respected by scheduler

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am trying to control which Airflow worker a task is executed on, however the queue parameter in the DAG definition is not being picked up by the scheduler.

I have defined a queue in my subdag operator:

```
xdata_run_etl = sub_dag_operator_with_celery_executor(
    subdag = build_xdata_etl_dag(dag, 'xdata_run_etl'),
    task_id = 'xdata_run_etl',
    dag = dag,
    trigger_rule='none_failed',
    queue='subdag'
)
```

And I can see the queue setting has been picked up. In the "Task Attributes" section in the UI `queue` is set to `subdag`.

However, when I trigger the DAG the scheduler is still sending the task to the default queue. As observed by the scheduler logs:

```
: [2020-04-02 20:38:49,581] {scheduler_job.py:1168} INFO - Sending ('run_etl', 'xdata_run_etl', datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 2, 17, 27, 38, 368220, tzininfo=<TimezoneInfo [UTC, GMT, +00:00:00, STD]>), 10) to executor with priority 2 and queue default
```

Expected behavior is that this task will be sent to the `subdag` queue and be ran on an Airflow worker that is listening on this queue. (`airflow worker -q subdag`). Actual behavior is that all tasks get sent to the default queue irrespective of the queue parameter being defined.

Airflow version: 1.10.9

Comment: I believe you are using celery worker. Could you check if the flower is showing queues for the workers.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to manual execution  of a dag,but you can also try setting the `default_queue` argument in `airflow.cfg` to your custom queue name and it will work.